# MySQL next/previous item by query - category first, then date

Tags: php, mysql

A list is sorted by date. However, rows can be marked "top priority", which will make sure that these rows always are displayed before the non-prioritized. The following SQL works great for displaying the list:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY (CASE WHEN category = 'top_priority'
THEN 0 ELSE 1 END), date DESC
```

When I click on a row I want to display next/previous buttons. Due to the two categories (priority first), I cannot use a simple query like this (PHP):

```
$next_id = "SELECT id from table WHERE date > $this_items_date"
```

Will I be able to figure out the next/previous ID when I know the current ID?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing off date, go by row number. As you're outputting the results, keep track of which row you're on. Then you can do a simple `SELECT ... ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1,$row+1` or `$row-1` for next/previous.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Forgot to mention that there are direct links to `item.php?id=30` (etc) from *other* pages than the row list. So I do not always have the possibility of passing the row number to the item page. And I would like to avoid looping through the whole table on the item page, as there are approx 10000 rows (list is created using [PEAR Pager](http://pear.php.net/package/Pager) BTW).

Comment: well, you can use LIMIT to show only a restricted row set. As long as you know the offset from which the current page was generated from in the "overall" recordset, you can adjust the LIMIT clause to start as appropriate. And with mysql's `sql_calc_found_rows`, you can easily figure out how many rows would be retrieved if a limit clause wasn't present.